# Is this function's use of vector useless?

Tags: c++

I saw this earlier and it doesn't make any sense to me:

```
void generate(std::vector<float> v)
{
 float f = generate_next_float();
 v.push_back(f);
}
```

If `v` was sent as a reference or a pointer, that would make sense. But instead it is sent by value, and therefore copied into the function, right? So anything done to `v` is immediately useless once the function terminates this `v` is out of scope, deleted.

Am I right?

That is, the function `generate_next_float()` might do something, so not useless, but the use of the `vector` here seems pointless. `f` does not depend on it, and nothing is returned.

Comment: Depends on what side-effects `generate_next_float()` has.

Comment: right, i edited the question and title to specify that I'm referring to the vector

Comment: I would wonder where you saw this? It looks like buggy code; someone forgot to include the `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as far as the vector is concerned, the `generate()` function is pointless; the changes to `v` won't be visible to the caller.

I have a feeling that the author of `generate()` missed to pass by reference as a overlook, not as a plan :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering std containers do not do implicit data sharing, that means you will pass a new deep copy into the function, push_back the float into that new copy that will then be discarded after the function is over. So, to me it would appear you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this function std::vector v will not change because you did not give the vector as a reference. It is just copied within the function and copy is changed but not the original one. You can use:

```
void generate(std::vector<float> &v) //input given as reference
{
  float f = generate_next_float();
  v.push_back(f);
}
```